# how to list all available url usage in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

```
urls = ( 'foo','foo','bar','bar', '/', index)
```

I want to list all available urls if visit / path. Any auto method?

Answer (score 1):

web.py uses the even-numbered elements to describe the path, and the odd-numbered elements to provide the url handler. That's why it's commonly written as:

```
urls = ('foo', 'foo',
        'bar', 'bar',
        '/', index)
```

So, the trick is simply print out even numbered elements:

```
>>> [urls[i] for i in xrange(0, len(urls), 2)]
['foo', 'bar', '/']
```

Now, there are some complications.

1. If you're hosting this via wsgi, then it may be that your webserver is passing to `webpy` only things prefixed with (for example) `/app`. So the "real" URLs should be `/app/foo`, '/app/bar`, etc. There's no way for you to tell from your application.
2. Your listed items could be (often are) regular expressions, so your produced list may not be a simple list of URLs. (Consider `dashboard/(mail|settings|status)` would permit three URLs: `dashboard/mail`, `dashboard/settings` and `dashboard/status`
3. Finally, the odd-numbered item, while usually a string, may instead by of class `web.application`, in which you'd recurse into that application, for all of its URLs as well.

For example:

```
import web

def p(app, prefix=None):
    mapping = app.mapping
    for pattern, what in mapping:
        if isinstance(what, basestring):
            print "{}{}".format(prefix + '/' if prefix else '', pattern)
        else:
            p(what, prefix=pattern)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # "blog" sub-application which handles blog-related urls                                                                                                                                  
    blog_urls = ('create', 'blog.Create', 'edit', 'blog.Edit', 'delete', 'blog.Delete')
    blog_app = web.application(blog_urls, globals())

    # "main" application which handles most urls, but passed blog URL to sub-application                                                                                                      
    main_urls = ('/account', 'account', '/settings', 'settings', '/blog', blog_app)
    main_app = web.application(main_urls, globals())
    p(main_app)
```

Running:

```
$ python foo.py
/account
/settings
/blog/create
/blog/edit
/blog/delete
```